# I just want to display data according to the day

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing a Timetable app for my department and I want to display Schedule for the day according to the day (i.e. Mon,tue,Wed etc)

```
package com.example.aravinth1.timetable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.Date;

public class Today extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Today");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //code for getting day
    Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String date = currentDate.toString();
    String arr[] = date.split(" ");
    String dayOfWeek = arr[0];
    //switch to select the layout
    //according to the day
    switch (dayOfWeek){
        case "Mon":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.moday, container, false);
        break;
        case "Tue":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tuesday, container, false);
        break;
        case "Wed":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wednesday, container, false);
        break;
        case "Thu":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.thursday, container, false);
        break;
        case "Fri":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.friday, container, false);
        break;
        case "Sat":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.saturday, container, false);
        break;
        case "Sun":
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sunday, container, false);
        break;
    }
    //how to return the inflated view
}
}
```

In the before mentioned code how do i return the inflated view according to the day? Is using switch statement corrent in this context?

Comment: You generally return something from Java method by using `return` statement, as you did inside `swith` (`break`s are useless there, by the way, because you never reach them). Please clarify what it is exactly that you're asking.

Comment: Even though switch statement return the view to be inflated, there is a error stating that no return statement for onCreate() function.

Comment: True, because not every branching path in your method ends with `return` statement. And that is because your `switch` is not necessarily exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class to get the current day of the week in Android.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 

switch (today) {    
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.moday, container, false);

    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tuesday, container, false);

    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        //etc...
}
```

Comment: Your approach is sound, but it doesn't actually answer the question. (Not that I understand what the question is).

Comment: Thanks..but I need to support API Level 14

Comment: Use the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html class